# Cannot Access Windows 2008 R2 Member Servers From The DMZ Zone to the Internal Network Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory

I have 2 Sharepoint Servers and 1 Fast Server(All Windows 2008 R2) moved From Internal Network To The DMZ layer. Now these 3 servers cannot communicate with the DC & DNS(Windows 2000). All the related ports have been open from the Firewall WatchGuard both ways.
But i can ping the DC & DNS. I can access the shared folder on both the DC & DNS.

Login is too slow, 
When i try to add a domain user to local administrators group, the following error occurs:

Error: RPC Server is Unavailable.
Event Log Error: **The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the user name. This could be caused by one of more of the following: 
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller. 
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller).

Comment: Which ports did you open? Is there any NAT'ing across either interface? Does the WatchGuard allow you to run a capture?

Comment: Application protocol

Protocol

Ports



Active Directory Web Services (ADWS) 

TCP

9389



Active Directory Management Gateway Service

TCP

9389



Global Catalog

TCP

3269



Global Catalog

TCP

3268



LDAP Server

TCP

389



LDAP Server

UDP

389



LDAP SSL

TCP

636



IPsec ISAKMP

UDP

500



NAT-T

UDP

4500



RPC

TCP

135



RPC randomly allocated high TCP ports¹

TCP

1024 - 5000
49152 - 65535²

Comment: Natting is done, with the 2 Public ip to 4 Private Ip's. 88.85.***.** to 172.16.18.2,3,4 & 5/29 where as the internal ip for DC & DNS is 192.168.1.7 & 192.168.1.5

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) to watch for packet retransmits from a server on DMZ when you try to do something that fails, like add a local admin.
2. You have increased complexity because your DMZ servers are >= 2008 and your old internal AD boxes are not. 2008 changed RPC port ranges. I see you've listed some in comments, but make sure [all ports on both 2003 & 2008 are open both ways](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179442).
3. You should route, not NAT, your DMZ to internal network. NAT will make things harder, if not impossible to get working. [Microsoft does have some suggestions on this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2009/04/22/dcs-and-network-address-translation.aspx).
4. Make this all easier by using IPSec tunneling, but I don't believe it can use NAT either.